# glob.glob not searching through all subdirectories for .tsv files

Tags: python, csv

I want to search through all of the subdirectories within a parent directory for all of the files with a `.tsv` extension. I have tried using the glob module but it does not return any of the subdirectory level information.

I have tried using glob.glob as a way to search through all of the subdirectories within a specific user specified location but it is not working. It simply returns an empty response, which is presumably all of the `.tsv` files that exist in the parent directory, which is none.

```
for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(location, '*.tsv')):
print(file)
```

What I am hoping to see is all of the `.tsv` files within the parent directory, even within subdirectories being printed in the shell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all files in a directory with extension .txt in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You're very close. You need to use the `**` character to tell glob to look in all sub-directories, and set `recursive=True`. Note this only works in python >= 3.5

```
for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(location, '**/*.tsv'), recursive=True):
    print(file)
```

I personally prefer the pathlib module.

```
from pathlib import Path
for file in Path(location).glob('**/*.tsv'):
    print(file)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I greatly appreciate it, I didn't even know to do that! In your opinion, what is the benefit of the pathlib over the glob module?